# Javascript cut string after 3th character in string

Tags: javascript, substring

I need to write function that returns 3strings after character ', ' so if there is none or 1 or 2 or 3 to return empty string if ', ' character is found else return 3 strings...i wrote these function but it is very cpu intensive...can be shorter and faster code?

https://jsfiddle.net/1nfyq327/

```
    var str = 'AAA BBB CC., DD EE, FF FF, GG GG, HH HH, II II, JJ JJ, GG GG';

    var res = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(', ', str.indexOf(', ', str.indexOf(', ')+1)+1));

    console.log(res);
```

Result is:

```
AAA BBB CC., DD EE, FF FF
```

Result is fine but i need faster code because it will execute on low power cpu so speed is very cruicial...

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: wanted result updated...

Comment: u can split on ', ' and merge 3 item, but better soulotion for problem like this is `regular expression`

Comment: What makes you think it’s CPU intensive?

Comment: Can you post example code using regular expression?

Comment: @user2631534 regular expressions will be neither quicker, nor more readable and overall are the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: regex is not faster but in cover all problem like this for learn regex try https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` , `slice` and `join`:

```js
var str = 'AAA BBB CC., DD EE, FF FF, GG GG, HH HH, II II, JJ JJ, GG GG';


var result = str.split(',').slice(0,3).join(',');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of speed there is not that much you can do.
The code you wrote runs in `O(n)`, which is the best possible time complexity for your problem.

You can play around with native functions (`split()`, `substring()`... that are implemented in c++ and therefore will run quickly) to see if one of them is faster, or rewrite it in pure javascript with a `for` loop. And compare the results.

In your case the best thing you can really do is write a little benchmark testing how fast your solution is and compare that. Althought there is high chance that there is something else in your code that runs slowly. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could split with a limit of [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and join the array.

```js
var string = 'AAA BBB CC., DD EE, FF FF, GG GG, HH HH, II II, JJ JJ, GG GG',
    result = string.split(',', 3).join(',')

console.log(result);
```